# Duplication of Sql Records

Tags: sql

I am trying to build a reminder application using c# and, i want to employee the concept of repeat in my application **[no repeat, daily, weekly ... ]**, but the problem i am facing is that how i shall store this reminder in the database.

I tried to duplicate the reminder and change it's date, but what if it has no end date then this one doesn't seem a very smart idea. And then i tried to keep one record in the database and when ever the date becomes past in case it's a repeated it modify the date to the next one, but here i facing the problem of how i search for reminders in a specific days. I wondered if there is a way that SQL can duplicate a record between two dates temporarily for the search.

So i am almost out of ideas right now, any help?!

Comment: can you post the SQL queries that you have tried?

Comment: no actually i didn't keep versions and lost both from accumulative tries

Comment: OK can you post the structure of your tables, and some sample data?

Comment: `Reminder ( remId bigint , remTit varchar(100), remDec varchar(300), stDate DateTime , enDate DateTime , remCheck char, remRepeat varChar(10000))`                                                    , and for samples u can suggest any  reminder between two dates or a reminder that has only starting date , and the problem is clear in the description above

Comment: for the remRepeat column, what on earth are you storing there? 10,000 characters is a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you should change any data dynamically in the reminder records.  You should add a variable called "remDayOfWeek" to the database -- this will be the day of the week that the user started if the user is to be reminded weekly. Let's say you scan once a day for users that need reminders.  All users with daily reminders will need reminders.  For users with weekly reminders, all those with "remDayOfWeek" equal to the current day of the week will get a reminder.

Comment: Sorry, I meant a "column", not a "variable" in the database.

Answer (score 0):

OK what I would suggest, is this:
Don't create individual reminders for each day you need a reminder. Give the DB the reminder, start/end dates, and the periodicity of the check (daily, weekly, monthly), and another column to keep track of the last time the user saw a reminder.
something like:

```
column: | ID  | title        | Desc        | Start | End | Period       | lastCheck         |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
type:   | INT | varchar(100) | varchar(300)| Date  | Date| INT (or Enum)| Date
```

The whole idea is, if the user skips a day you don't need to remind them twice, and you don't really care about what happened to expired reminders, just the most recent.

Assuming the following:

```
no-repeat = 0
daily = 1
weekly = 2
monthly = 3
```

you could pull all the reminders you need for a particular date by using: (assuming SQL Server, you didn't specify)

```
SELECT * FROM Reminder 
WHERE (GetDate() BETWEEN Start AND End) 
AND ((Period = 0 AND lastChecked IS NULL) 
OR (Period = 1 AND GetDate() > DATEADD(day,1,lastChecked))
OR (Period = 2 AND GetDate() > DATEADD(week,1,lastChecked))
OR (Period = 3 AND GetDate() > DATEADD(month,1,lastChecked)));
```

If you want the reminder to be 24 hours/1 week/1 month exactly from the last time checked that will be fine. otherwise use `CONVERT (date, GETDATE())` to ignore the time the user checked.

Finally, update `lastChecked` to the current time after the user dismisses a reminder.